# Current Global Climate Dataset

Tags: data, climate

Where can I find gridded Current Global Climate Datasets (Mean Temperature and Precipitation) at 30 second resolution?

Comment: http://data.worldbank.org/developers/climate-data-api

Answer (score 2):

I think that http://www.worldclim.org should do the trick as they offer datasets in different resolutions including 30 sec.

Comment: Thanks zankuralt. But the worldclim has the baseline Datasets corresponding only upto 2000. Whether will I get data upto 2010.

Comment: Did you check this [link](https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data/global-land-precipitation-and-temperature-willmott-matsuura-university-delaware)?

Answer (score 0):

for the land-masses you can find the data here:
http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/download.html
http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/download.html#T2014 gives you gridded monthly Air Temp for the years 1900 to 2014 and
http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/download.html#P2014 gives you gridded monthly Precipitation for the years 1900 to 2014
the format is good documentated and you can easily construct different normal-climate-periods  e.g. 1981 -2010, 1931 - 1960 ...

Answer (score 0):

Global Solar Atlas features with global raster dataset of **long-term average of air temperature**, 30 arcsec, currently calculated for a period 1994-2015. Data source are CFSR and CFSv2 data from NOAA, postprocessed by [Solargis](http://solargis.com). All metadata is included, follow:

- http://globalsolaratlas.info/downloads/world
- or the same data at
  http://solargis.com/en/maps-and-gis-data/download/world

**Precipitation** - very reasonable quality raster data is provided by [DWD](https://www.dwd.de) within a GPCC (Global Precipitation Climatology Centre) project. Monthly, daily and various aggregations available. However, the resolution is coarser (check the latest release of data). Follow

- https://www.dwd.de/EN/ourservices/gpcc/gpcc.html